# How to find 5th highest salary in each department?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a attach table having 7 records in each department.
I need to make a query that finds the 5th highest salary for each department.

[image]

Comment: You forgot your code you wrote that produces the wrong output.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Please tag only the database that you are using.

Comment: [Find the 3rd Maximum Salary for each department](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46371935/find-the-3rd-maximum-salary-for-each-department-based-on-table-data)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the 3rd Maximum Salary for each department based on table data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46371935/find-the-3rd-maximum-salary-for-each-department-based-on-table-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()` (*if* you are running MySQL, this requires version 8.0):

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by department order by salary desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 5
```